# What does "do you like potatoes" mean?

Tags: idioms, slang, jokes

I heard "Do you like potatoes" from a native speaker, but I couldn't understand him. 
Could you help me asap?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: What was the context that makes you believe that this is a joke? Are you sure that was exactly what was said?

Comment: What don't you understand about 'do you like' questions and 'potatoes'?

Comment: @KillingTime No context exists. Because he wrote that sentence only. That's why I am asking here.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, I know "I like something" style. But I'd like to know if it has a special meaning that it's difficult for non-natives like me to know like idioms.

Comment: Why do you think it is a joke? Could it be possible that he wants to know if you like potatoes?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, while chatting with him, I had read it several times. I supposed that he doesn't want to know if I like potatoes...

Comment: Why don't you ask him what he meant, instead of us?

Comment: The context is: what medium was it written in? Online, in a letter, on a blackboard, etc.? What had happened before? What were the sentences before that one? What's your relation to the other person, etc. There's a huge amount of context you're not telling us.

Comment: @CJDennis, he wrote it on the chatting board. He wrote one sentence only. I only answered "No". I am working with him on a remote basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Omitting the obvious meaning, that is, if you were being served dinner, potatoes has a wide range of slang meanings, many of which the native speaker may have had in mind:

Possible meaning in the context of "Do you like potatoes?"

Money: "Do you like money?"

Penis: Do you like penises?

Menstruation (used to avoid the term "period" around those who might be offended or confused): "Do you like periods?"

Lazy dudes, couch potatoes: Do you like lazy dudes?

http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/potatoes

A girl/woman who is not considered a babe: "Do you like plain women?"

https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=potato(A word used by some people to describe themselves in a humorous way. Generally used by girls with low self-esteem who think they aren't attractive and/or cute enough to make guys, especially their crushes, interested in them.